# "pipenv" не является внутренней или внешней командой

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Я пытаюсь избавиться от ошибки:

```
"pipenv" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Пробую установить pipenv командой: pip install pipenv

После этого оно пишет:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pipenv in c:\users\develop\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (2018.11.26)
    Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=36.2.1 in c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages (from pipenv) (39.0.1)
    Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5 in c:\users\develop\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from pipenv) (0.4.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: pip>=9.0.1 in c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages (from pipenv) (10.0.1)
    Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\users\develop\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from pipenv) (16.1.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: certifi in c:\users\develop\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from pipenv) (2018.11.29)
```

Когда пробую, например, посмотреть версию pipenv'a, то оно пишет:

```
"pipenv" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Попробуйте перейти в директорию, где у Вас установлен Питон, в ней зайти в директорию Scripts и прописать pipenv.

Comment: прописал pipenv в директории Scripts Питона и вывело опции и команды:
Usage: pipenv [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Comment: Тогда добавьте полный путь до pipenv в переменную окружения `PATH`

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте директорию

`C:\Users\develop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts`

в PATH, закройте и снова откройте командную строку.